# PHP Table inline editing - Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to create an inline edit function on my table, the user should be able to retype the values, and click the 'Save' button to update the database record.

I've hit a problem with the javascript function, its not reverting me to the next page as per 'window.location.href', which would be the php update qry page, that reverts me back to the original page to view the changes made.

The javascript function is meant to get the old id , and all of the possibly new td's within the record, which the user may have inline edited.

I had this working for the id itself, but with the addition of all the new values, ive messed up either on the js function or the action but (may the 'this'?) not exactly sure. I know mysql is rubbish and so on, im focusing on functionality at the time being.

**JS FUNCTION**

```
function edit_user(id,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k) {

var tr = a.parentNode.parentNode;
var awb = String(tr.querySelector(".a").innerHTML);

var tb = b.parentNode.parentNode;
var del = String(tb.querySelector(".b").innerHTML);

var tc = c.parentNode.parentNode;
var vsl = String(tc.querySelector(".c").innerHTML);

var td = d.parentNode.parentNode;
var cli = String(td.querySelector(".d").innerHTML);

var te = e.parentNode.parentNode;
var pcs = String(te.querySelector(".e").innerHTML);

var tf = f.parentNode.parentNode;
var wgt = String(tf.querySelector(".f").innerHTML);

var tg = g.parentNode.parentNode;
var car = String(tg.querySelector(".g").innerHTML);

var th = h.parentNode.parentNode;
var snd = String(th.querySelector(".h").innerHTML);

var ti = i.parentNode.parentNode;
var stt = String(ti.querySelector(".i").innerHTML);

var tj = j.parentNode.parentNode;
var ard = String(tj.querySelector(".j").innerHTML);

var tk = k.parentNode.parentNode;
var ctm = String(tk.querySelector(".k").innerHTML);

// run query on server:
window.location.href = 'http://at-web2.comp.glam.ac.uk/students/14075377/14075377/php/edit-livedashboard-import.php?id='+id+'&newawb='+awbno+'&newvsl='+vsl+'&newcli='+cli+'&newpcs='+pcs+'&newwgt='+wgt+'&newcar='+car+'&newsnd='+snd+'&newstt='+stt+'&neward='+ard;;
return false;}
```

**TABLE ACTION BUTTON**

```
$awb = $get_info["AwbNo"];
echo "<a href='' onclick='return edit_user($awb,here,here,here,here,here,here,here,here,here);'>&nbspSave&nbsp</a>";
```

**PHP UPDATE**

```
include("../dbinfo.inc.php");
$comm=@mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
$rs=@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database"); 

$id = $_GET['id'];
$newawb = $_GET['awbno'];
$newvsl = $_GET['vsl'];
$newcli = $_GET['cli'];
$newpcs = $_GET['pcs'];
$newwgt = $_GET['wgt'];
$newcar = $_GET['car'];
$newsnd = $_GET['snd'];
$newstt = $_GET['stt'];
$neward = $_GET['ard'];

$sql = "UPDATE tbl_import SET AwbNo='$newawb',ClientCode='$newcli',VesselName='$newvsl',Pieces='$newpcs',Weight='$newwgt',Carrier='$newcar',Sender='$newsnd',Status='$newstt',ArrivalDate='$neward',WHERE AwbNo='$id';"; 

echo ("id=$id,awb=$newawb,vsl=$newvsl,cli=$newcli,pcs=$newpcs,wgt=$newwgt,car=$newcar,send=$newsnd, status=$newstt, date=$neward .\n\n\n");

mysql_query($sql)or die("Update Error: ".mysql_error());
mysql_close();        
//commented header so can see echoed vals sent from js
//header("Location: ../livedashboard.php"); //redirect to relevant page
```

Comment: Have heard about loops?

Comment: Also **SQL injection alert**. This code is subject to SQL injections, which is a very severe security issue. And it's using the mysql_* functions, which are deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

First thing try to print:

```
console.log('php/edit-livedashboard-import.php?id='+id+awb+del+vsl+cli+pcs+wgt+car+snd+stt+ard+ctm);
```

it should be like this:

```
'php/edit-livedashboard-import.php?id='+id+ '&awb='+awd+'&del='+del...etc;
```

Second thing:

Add full url instead of dir :

```
window.location.href = 'php/edit-livedashboard-import.php?id='+id+aw...;
```

ex.

```
window.location.href = 'http://example.com/php/edit-livedashboard-import.php?id=...';
```

Comment: Hi Khaled, changed the urls, ive also made abit of head way, so ive updated my code to reflect this. At the moment, ive managed to get it to redirect to the php update page, and for testing purposes, im echoing all the values, BUT its only working with the 'id', the newawb,newvsl,newcli,etc isnt passing any data and being echoed as '' (null).

Comment: Should be like this: `'php/edit-livedashboard-import.php?id='+id+ '&awb='+awd+'&del='+del...etc;`